# Can you update a lookup record field in apex? Such as object.relationship__r.field__c = x?

Tags: apex, lookup, field-update

quick question here that's in the title. Is there any way to update the relationship record field in apex without looping through that object after querying a list of ids.

Example snippet below that currently is not working:

```
Opportunity o = [Select Id, lookup__r.field__c, lookup__r.field2__c from Opportunity];

o.lookup__r.field__c = 'test';
o.lookup__r.field2__c ++;

update o;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,You can do that. You need an additional DML statement. You need to do like this:-

```
Opportunity o = [Select Id, lookup__r.field__c, lookup__r.field2__c from Opportunity];

o.lookup__r.field__c = 'test';
o.lookup__r.field2__c ++;

update o; //it will update opportunity

update o.lookup__r; //it will update the relationship record
```

Comment: Hi thanks, are you also able to do this with a list? Or would that involve dml statements inside a loop?

Comment: @AlexanderAtkinsoon You can add the `__r` values to a `list<sobject>` and update them at the end of the loop.